# JUNIT to skip IO handling and verify only the logic

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I was asked some question like this in an interview.

So basically, the question is like this:

You have a method like below:

```
public void methodToBeTested() {
    //step 1 open file, if not exist create new one
    //step 2 String rst = reverseStr();
    //step 3 write rst to file in step 1
}
```

So the question is how to write a unit test to test only the reverseStr logic without doing the IO handling of step1 and step3 each time?

Comment: Can you share the entire class and explain what exactly is the problem?

Comment: There is no complete class. The interviewer fist ask me to implement reverseStr(). Then, she write an warper class similar to above one. Which calls reverseStr(). And ask how to write unit test without calling the IO handler. I thought there could be some JUNIT functionality that I did not aware of. But, it might just be the interviewer is silly.

Comment: Maybe something was lost in translation, but this doesn't make any sense to me. If you want to test just the functionality of `reverseStr()`, write a test for it - don't look for magical ways to play around with its wrapper method.

Answer (score 0):

refactor your code: extract method `reverseStr` and make it [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). this method should contain all the logic (transforming one string into another). also make change visibility to at least package private. then you can call this method in your tests however you want without dealing with files

Comment: I think you can not do refactor.